# Columns with Drop Down Menus in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm an amateur VBA user and need some guidance...

I have two worksheets in Excel (1) Billing, (2) Contract.  Billing Sheet has a column with a drop-down menu with billing descriptions. Columns B & C are start & stop times. Column D are 'cost' that located on in the Contract Sheet and are associated with the billing description.  Depending on the billing description, the cost in Column D (Billing Sheet) populates.

I need help with either a formula (if possible) or VBA code that if the user inputs something from the drop-down that exceeds the contract, the 'contract decription' will replace the initial drop-down entry and the overage desciption will automatically drop down to the row beneath as well as automatically populate the start & stop times in that same row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would making a selection from the drop-down "exceed the contract" ?

Comment: The drop-down has options that include the contract billing and an option in excess of the contract (ie. contract = 1000, excess = 2000, 3000)...you can only double or triple the contracted amount.  if the user selects 2000, I want the initial selected option (from drop-down) to change to 1000 and the row below to automatically populate to 1000. Hope this makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: So if they choose the "triple" option then what would happen? Would two additional rows be inserted?

Comment: No, I'd like the 2nd row to populated to 2000 while the initial row is 1000.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: How is column D calculated: if your macro is potentially going to change the value selected from the drop-down, should ColumnD then reflect the new value?

Comment: Column D is populated from the drop-down option which is associated by a Lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (goes in the Worksheet code module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const VAL_TRIPLE As String = "Triple"
    Const VAL_DOUBLE As String = "Double"
    Dim rng As Range, cost

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Set rng = Target.Cells(1)

    If rng.Column = 1 And rng.Row > 1 Then

        DoEvents 'run the cost lookup...
        cost = rng.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value

        With rng
            If .Value = VAL_DOUBLE Or .Value = VAL_TRIPLE Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False

                .Offset(1, 0).Insert
                .Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value
                If IsNumeric(cost) Then
                   .Offset(1, 3).Value = cost * IIf(.Value = VAL_TRIPLE, 2, 1)
                End If
                .Value = "replacement" 'how to know what goes here?
                .Offset(1, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Offset(1, 2).Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value

                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```